# Removing jquery 2.2.4 from drupal 8 (It is loading it on its own)

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-8

I need to remove jquery 2.2.4 from drupal 8 (It is loading it on its own). This should be working but its not.

`libraries-override:
  core/jquery: false`

i am putting this on my info.yml file

Has anyone managed to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet tried Drupal 8 but after a quick search in the Drupal issues queue I've found out the following:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1974580

Maybe it could help?

PS: Sorry but I don't have yet the reputation to comment - Only answers are acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt help my case. Thanks a lot for your answer though! It may help on a similar case.